# How to manage command execution speed when working with selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

I would like  to be able to change the speed with which the mouse moves in selenium.

I've found `DefaultSelenium` class, but this one is not static, and I don't know how to use it to set delays in individual webdrivers.

Can anyone point me to a good example of how to set execution speed in selenium, preferably in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can't. WebDriver provides no intrinsic way to manage this. You might be able to simulate such a thing by using the `Actions` class to break up a single mouse movement into many steps, pausing for a short time between steps.